# send age as birthdate when submitting reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript

When the user types age in input I want to send this age as birthdate, for a month and day today's date.

> "birthDate": "1996-04-20T20:43:40.909Z",

like this

**.html**

```
<input matInput formControlName="birthDate" type="text" class="form-control age" placeholder="Age" required>
```

**.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      formArray: this._formBuilder.array([
        this._formBuilder.group({
          birthDate: ['', [Validators.min(18), Validators.max(50)]],
        }),
      ])

    });
  }

 onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.formGroup.value);
    this.service.calculate(this.formGroup.value).subscribe(
      (res:any)=>{
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-6xojcb?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: and your date should be no less that number 18 and no more than number 50?  here `birthDate: ['' <---here` you provide initial value. set t as a date that you want, or anything else

Comment: I think it makes no sense to actually store and send the time part, the day and the month. None of these values have any use nor are they true. Just send and ask for the year of birth (which is btw. a way better query to ask for someone's age than asking for the age directly).

Comment: @maio290 hey, api is build like that, so i need to pass month and day like that :(

Comment: @sabrinaspellman Well, you can still rather query for the year of birth instead of the age. That the API is designed that way is pretty poor, I feel your pain :<

Comment: @maio290 haha thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const birthDateValue = 23; // Get value from the form control
const date = new Date();
const year = date.getFullYear() - birthDateValue;
date.setYear(year);

console.log(date.toISOString())
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, i did your solution on onsubmit method but i get this error
Property 'setYear' does not exist on type 'Date'

Comment: If you have that error, just switch from date.setYear(year) to date.setFullYear(year);

Comment: now i get this error Cannot read property 'value' of null
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-6xojcb?file=app/app.component.ts
here is my stackblitz, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You have to learn to debug things :) In your case, not sure why you are using nested form groups in this situation, but you have a form group that consists of form array controls and each control in that array is a form group that has form control, that's really too much for this case...  

this.formGroup.controls.formArray.controls[0].get('birthDate').value will get your data, but this is too complex for your example. Try simplifying things first and then add extra complex logic, doing this way you will just head stuck with nesting forms (at this point, totally unnecessary)

Comment: i am using mat-stepper with single form for my project thats why i have nested form groups

Comment: Take a look at examples: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/examples

Comment: yes i use this example https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview#using-a-single-form
i updated stackblitz, now i can't debug this error Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

Answer (score 1):

As I already stated in the comments, querying for the year of birth is a better way to ask for a person's age.

If you are free to change this in your application, you could easily build the string without having to use a date object:

```
createDateForYearOfBirth(yearOfBirth)
{
    return yearOfBirth+"-01-01T00:00:00.000Z";
}
```

Querying for the age will yield in wrong results.

Example: A person was born on `1995-06-20` - his current age is therefore `25`. If you subtract 25 from 2021, you'd get 1996 as year of birth, which isn't correct.

And my solution is faulty too for that purpose (when recalculating the age of someone, he'll always be a year older on the 1st of January). But that really depends on what you actually need the year of birth / age for.